# station out graf and get rid of debounce

Tags: c, graph

I will straighten out this graph but i cant get my head around it.

This is my array:

```
3.2900
3.3000
3.3300
3.3200
3.2900
3.2800
3.2800
3.2600
3.2800
3.2900
3.3000
3.3000
3.3200
3.3100
3.3200
3.3300
3.3500
3.3100
3.3200
3.2700
3.2800
3.2800
3.2900
3.2800
0.1000
0.0100
3.2800
3.2800
0.1000
0.1000
3.1500
3.0800
0.0400
0.0500
0.0600
0.0500
0.0200
0.0100
0.0200
0.0300
0.0200
0.0500
0.0500
0.0800
0.0700
0.0500
0.0500
0.1000
0.1500
0.0500
```

And the array i want looks like this:

```
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

I have done a code to get rid of the noise, But i cant get rid of the dips.
That means i need too look back in my array, but i don't know how.
The code i have to take out the noise is:

int debounce(double src[], double dst[], int length)

{

```
int i;

for (i =0 ; i < length; i++ )

{
    if ( src[i] < 0.3 )                 
    {
        (dst[i]= 0);
    }
    if ( src[i] > 3 )               
    {
        (dst[i]=3.3);
    }

    if (dst[i] == dst[i-2])
    {

    }
    /**
     *
     if (dst[i] == dst[i-1])
    {
        {
            if (dst[i] == dst[i-2])
            {
                dst[i]=dst[i];
            }
            if (dst[i] != dst[i-2])
            {
                dst[i-1]=dst[i];
            }
        }
    }
    */
}


    return -1;
}
```

I have tried different If statement, but i can't figure out how i can use them here.(for example you can see one of many if statement i tried, in the part i comment out in my code.)

The array i get from this peace of cod looks like this.

```
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
3.3000
     0
     0
3.3000
3.3000
     0
     0
3.3000
3.3000
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

The graph i have now looks like this, But i want to get a graph without the two dips. Hope you understand my question,
Best regards

[image]

Comment: `if (dst[i] == dst[i-2])` address the `dst` array out of bounds on first 2 loop

Comment: Straighten out graf and get rid of debounce* (sorry for my bad English) :)

Comment: As far as I understood you want to set `dst[i]` to 0 after the **first** match of `src[i] < 0.3` and till the end of `dst` despite other values ?